# Load the xml file into array of custom class

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file with 200 of the following data

```
    <Dices>
      <Dice>
        <Sequence>1</Sequence>
        <Dice1>2</Dice1>
        <Dice2>2</Dice2>
      </Dice>
      <Dice>
        <Sequence>2</Sequence>
        <Dice1>3</Dice1>
        <Dice2>4</Dice2>
      </Dice>
```

and in my main program, I have a class of "Dice"

```
int _sequence, _dice1, _dice2
public Dice(sequence, dice1, dice2) ......
public int sequence { get { return _sequence; } set { _sequence = value; } }
public int dice1 { get { return _dice1; } set { _dice1 = value; } }
public int dice2 { get { return _dice2; } set { _dice2 = value; } }
```

How do I load the xml into an array of Dice class?
Thanks!

Oops, I forgot to include my own code
I thought this would work, but apparently it returns null for all
Please take a look for me?

```
Dice[] load_dices = (from dice in load_xml.Elements("Dice")
                                 select new Dice
                                            {
                                                sequence = (int)dice.Element("Sequence"), 
                                                dice1 = (int)dice.Element("Dice1"), 
                                                dice2 = (int)dice.Element("Dice2")
                                            })
                                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first select the root element

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<Dices>
  <Dice>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <Dice1>2</Dice1>
    <Dice2>2</Dice2>
  </Dice>
  <Dice>
    <Sequence>2</Sequence>
    <Dice1>3</Dice1>
    <Dice2>4</Dice2>
  </Dice></Dices>";
        XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        Dice[] load_dices = (from dice in xd.Root.Elements("Dice")
                             select new Dice
                             {
                                 Sequence = (int)dice.Element("Sequence"),
                                 Dice1 = (int)dice.Element("Dice1"),
                                 Dice2 = (int)dice.Element("Dice2")
                             }).ToArray();
        foreach (var x in load_dices)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
public class Dice
{
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public int Dice1 { get; set; }
    public int Dice2 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", Sequence, Dice1, Dice2);
    }
}
```

Print:

```
1       2       2
2       3       4
```

Link: http://rextester.com/IFABI55474

Comment: Thanks for your help! I later found out what really went wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Xml.Serialization attributes

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[XmlRoot("dices")]
public class DicesElement
{
    [XmlArray("dice")]
    [XmlArrayItem("dice", Type = typeof(DiceElement))]
    public List<DiceElement> Dice { get; set;}
}
```

...

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class DiceElement
{
    [XmlElement("Sequence")]
    public string Sequence { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Dice1")]
    public string Dice1{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Dice2")]
    public string Dice2{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize them and the heavy lifting is done.

More info on deserializing: https://blog.udemy.com/csharp-serialize-to-xml/

Answer (score 0):

Another part that might help is you must use the default namespace when attempting to find items.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileInfo.FullName, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
    var defaultNs = xDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();        
    var packageElement = xDoc.Descendants(defaultNs + "package")                                
                                .Where(n => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.Attribute("id").Value) == false
                                            && n.Attribute("id").Value.Equals("SomeValue", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                            && n.Attribute("version").Value.Equals("1.1.2") == false)
                                .SingleOrDefault();
```

Without adding the default namespace value to the Descendants method it would not find anything.  I'm not sure that this is necessarily your problem but I just wanted to provide this information for you as well.